# Using (trying to) recursion to reverse lists within a list

Tags: python

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)

def deep_reverse(p):
    initial = []
    for v, e in enumerate(p):
        if is_list(e):
            #print p[v][::-1]
            initial.append(p[v][::-1])
            deep_reverse(e)
    return initial

p = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6, [7, 8]]]]]
print deep_reverse(p)
```

I get `[[[4, [5, 6, [7, 8]]], 3, 2]]`, expected at least (I haven't bothered to figure out how to not lose the very first list `[1[...]]` yet) `[[[[6, 5, [8, 7]], 4], 3, 2]]`.

As you can see the code only reverses `[ [2, 3]]` --> [[3, 2]].
What did I do wrong? Haven't I though about?

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it:

```
def deep_reverse(p):
    return [deep_reverse(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x for x in p[::-1]]

p = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6, [7, 8]]]]]
print deep_reverse(p)   #  [[[[[8, 7], 6, 5], 4], 3, 2], 1]
```

Comment: This is restrictive and doesn't need to be - it will only work for `list`s, which is unpythonic and inflexible. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15449885/722121) for a version without that restriction.

Answer (score 3):

A more generic, Pythonic answer to this, based on [Pavel Anossov's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15449630/722121) is as follows:

```
def deep_reversed(seq):
    return [deep_reversed(x) if (isinstance(x, collections.Sequence) and 
                                not isinstance(x, str)) else x 
            for x in reversed(seq)]
```

Note that this is for Python 3.x, in Python 2.x, you will want [`isinstance(x, basestring)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#basestring) instead to allow for Unicode strings.

This answer is a good one, as it will work correctly with any object that acts as a sequence - be it a list, a tuple, or a custom class. This means it's much more flexible.

Edit: If you wanted it to reverse strings internally:

```
def deep_reversed(seq):
    for x in reversed(seq):
        if isinstance(x, collections.Sequence):
            if isinstance(x, str):
                yield "".join(reversed(x))
            else:
                yield deep_reversed(x)
        else:
            yield x
```

Again, in 2.x, use `isinstance(x, basestring)`.

Comment: So why not reverse strings? Why will it receive any sequence and return always a list?

Comment: @PavelAnossov For one, because all strings are iterable, so when a string is iterated over and length 1 strings are produced, they would then be iterated over, producing infinite recursion. This could, of course, be special-cased. The main issue is that generally, in cases like this, we want strings to be treated as a single item, not a sequence. (Edit: Added a string-reversing version).

Comment: @PavelAnossov As to always returning a list, that's fine. Python is duck typed, there is no reason to believe that what you put in will always be what you get out. It could be modified to be a generator, but seeing as reversing will always require generating the whole reversed sequence first, there is no benefit to doing so. (Edit: My string-reversing version is a generator as it reads much better that way).

Comment: My point is we haven't received detailed enough specifications, so all assumptions are just assumptions. I personnaly wouldn't reverse tuples as well, I'd consider them also a single item.

Comment: @PavelAnossov Obviously, there is that possibility, however, the most common case is expressed here. Apart from excluding strings (which my edited post now gives a version for), this is how the built-in `reversed()` functions, and so it makes sense to have a function mirror that.

Comment: What do you mean? `reversed` is not recursive. When passed a string, it will return an iterator over a reversed string.

Comment: @PavelAnossov What I mean is that `reversed()` will reverse any sequence, not just `list`s. That's how my function works, except it's recursive. This makes it's behaviour more intuitive for Python users.

Answer (score 2):

In the recursive calls to `deep_reverse(e)` you are not using the returned value. It looks as though you are expecting it to modify the input list

You can change it to something like this:

```
def deep_reverse(p):
    initial = []
    for e in p[::-1]:
        if is_list(e):
            initial.append(deep_reverse(e)])
        else:
            initial.append(e)
    return initial
```

Answer (score 2):

There are already many nice solutions, but maybe this is the algorithm you are trying:

```
def is_list(p):
    return isinstance(p, list)

def deep_reverse(p):
    initial = p[::-1] # reverse this level
    for v, e in enumerate(initial): 
        if is_list(e): # for all the sublist in this level
            initial[v] = deep_reverse(e) # recursively call deep_reverse to reverse the sublist
    return initial

p = [1, [2, 3, [4, [5, 6, [7, 8]]]]]
print deep_reverse(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your purpose:

```
import collections
def dr(p):
     r=[]
     for i in p:
      if isinstance(i,collections.Iterable):
       r.append(dr(i))
      else:
       r.append(i)
     return r[::-1]
```